# Can i put a googlemap in the middle section of my user interface?

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface

i need that my user interface haves 3 sections

NORTH SECTION: four textviews with info about a user

MIDDLE SECTION:  a googlemap view with the position of the user

SOUTH SECTION: a textview with time of last position, and a button to actualice the position (retrieving it from a database)

is this possible? i can't find any information about that on google or android developers guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative layout having three children layouts.
In the second layout add mapview.This will require to add google map apikey in its properties.

```
<LinearLayout>
      com.google.android.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapview" 
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:layout_height="380px" 
            android:layout_width="540px" 
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" 
            android:apiKey="your key"/>
</LinearLayout>
```